# Modify built-in ember.js view

Tags: view, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to ember.js and looking at the built-in views: http://emberjs.com/guides/views/built-in-views/

I understand working with views using a data-template name and editing it from Ember.view.extend, but how do I modify these ember.js built in views? And how do view names work?

For example, in my index.html:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="test">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='title'}}</p>
    <h3>Body</h3>
    <p>{{view Ember.TextArea viewName="bodyArea" valueBinding='text'}}</p>
    <h2>Output</h2>
    {{title}}
    {{text}}
 </script>
```

Now how might I set the background color of the textarea with the viewName="bodyArea" in my app.js? In the ember.js guide linked to above they show that you can set a viewName property in handlebars but don't show how you might edit it in javascript....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have three questions here:

1. How do I set a background color on the text area? {{view Ember.TextArea viewName="bodyArea" valueBinding='text' classNames="my-class-name'}} and then use CSS to style "my-class-name".
2. How do I modify a view with custom behavior?

> ```
> App.MyTextArea = Em.TextArea.extend({
>   didInsertElement: function(){
>    //do something cool here.
>   }
> });
> ```

In template:

> {{view App.MyTextArea}}

1. How do I use view name? I'm not sure that is something that is used a lot, but if you define a container view you could access a child view with this.get('myViewName'). As things are more encapsulated within ember a lot of the old uses for viewName no longer seem relevant. Someone else might be able to chime in on this feature.

As an aside you can also use a new short hand for built in views:

> {{textarea value=title}} will do the same as {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='title'}}